# Making constant legend symbol in coefplot -- stata

Tags: visualization, stata

I created the plot below using coefplot:
[image]

My issue is that in the legend, some of the symbols are showing up as points and some as lines. How do I make it so they all show up as points? For reference, my code is here:

```
coefplot(a b c d e f)(g h i j)(k l m)(n o p q r)(s t u v w), keep(ZArea1_z ZArea2_z ZArea3_z ZArea6_z ZArea7_z ZArea8_z ZArea9_z ZArea11_z ZArea11_z ZArea12_z ZArea13_z ZArea14_z ZArea15_z ZArea16_z ZArea17_z ZArea18_z) xline(0) msymbol(S) xlabel(,grid) ylabel(,labsize(small)) coeflabels(, wrap(30)) legend(order(1 " General Practice" 2 "HPSA" 3 "Medicaid" 4 "Rural" 5 "URM") rows(2) size(small))
```

Comment: The question falls far short of a minimal reproducible example, which is the standard on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example That said,`coefplot` is a popular community-contributed command (as you're asked to explain: see `stata` tag wiki), but not one I use myself (which is why I won't answer)  If  you don't get an answer here you would be immensely better off asking on Statalist.